# How to create only one table with SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I am unable to create a single table using SQLAlchemy.

I can create it by calling `Base.metadata.create_all(engine)` but as the number of table grows, this call takes a long time.

I create table classes on the fly and then populate them.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, Sequence, String, Date, Float, BIGINT
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

Base = declarative_base()

class HistoricDay():

    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    #  Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume, Adj Close
    date = Column(Date)
    open = Column(Float)
    high = Column(Float)
    low = Column(Float)
    close = Column(Float)
    volume = Column(BIGINT)
    adjClose = Column(Float)

    def __init__(self, date, open, high, low, close, volume, adjClose):
        self.date = date
        self.open = open
        self.high = high
        self.low = low
        self.close = close
        self.volume = volume
        self.adjClose = adjClose

def build_daily_history_table_repr(self):
        return "<"+self.__tablename__+"('{}','{}','{}','{}','{}','{}','{}','{}')>".format(self.id, self.date, self.open, self.high, self.low, self.close, self.volume, self.adjClose)

def build_daily_history_table(ticket):
    classname = ticket+"_HistoricDay"
    globals()[classname] = type(classname, (HistoricDay,Base), {'__tablename__' : ticket+"_daily_history"})
    setattr(globals()[classname], '__repr__', build_daily_history_table_repr)

# Initialize the database :: Connection & Metadata retrieval
engine = create_engine('mysql+cymysql://root@localhost/gwc?charset=utf8&use_unicode=0', pool_recycle=3600) # ,echo = True

# SqlAlchemy :: Session setup
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

# Create all tables that do not already exist
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

# SqlAlchemy :: Starts a session
session = Session()

ticketList = getTicketList()

for ticket in ticketList:
    build_daily_history_table(ticket)
    class_name = ticket+"_HistoricDay"

    meta_create_all_timer = time.time()
    # Create all tables that do not already exist
    # globals()[class_name]('2005-07-24',0,0,0,0,0,0).create(engine)  #doesn't work
    #(globals()[class_name]).__table__.create(engine) #doesn't work
    # session.commit() #doesn't work

    #Base.metadata.create_all(engine) # works but gets very slow
    print("  meta_create_all_timer {}s".format(time.time()-meta_create_all_timer))

    data = getData(ticket)

    for m_date, m_open, m_close, m_high, m_low, m_volume, m_adjClose in data:
        entry = globals()[class_name](m_date, m_open, m_high, m_low, m_close, m_volume, m_adjClose)
        session.add(entry)

    session.commit()
```

I saw in the [documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/metadata.html) that you can do

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')

meta = MetaData()

employees = Table('employees', meta,
    Column('employee_id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('employee_name', String(60), nullable=False, key='name'),
    Column('employee_dept', Integer, ForeignKey("departments.department_id"))
)
employees.create(engine)
```

However, I'm not able to figure out how to do the same thing as `Table` does, with `declarative_base()`.

How can I do that with classes that inherit from `declarative_base()`?

Comment: it should be `HistoricDay(Base)`

Comment: No because HistoricDay has no attribute tablename.  
The generated class inherits from Base : globals()[classname] = type(classname, (HistoricDay,Base), {'tablename' : ticket+"_daily_history"})

Answer (score 40, accepted):

> Above, the declarative_base() callable returns a new base class from
>   which all mapped classes should inherit. When the class definition is
>   completed, a new Table and mapper() will have been generated.
>
> The resulting table and mapper are accessible via `__table__` and
>   `__mapper__` attributes

(From [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/extensions/declarative.html))

**Therefore:**

```
def build_daily_history_table(ticket):
    classname = ticket + "_HistoricDay"
    ticket = type(classname, (Base, HistoricDay), {'__tablename__' : ticket+"_daily_history"})
    ticket.__repr__ =  build_daily_history_table_repr
    return ticket

build_daily_history_table("test").__table__.create(bind = engine)
```

**Output:**

```
2013-10-04 22:36:53,263 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine 
CREATE TABLE test_daily_history (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    date DATE, 
    open FLOAT, 
    high FLOAT, 
    low FLOAT, 
    close FLOAT, 
    volume BIGINT, 
    "adjClose" FLOAT, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)


2013-10-04 22:36:53,263 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2013-10-04 22:36:53,263 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT
```

Credit goes to [javex's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19175311/how-to-create-only-one-table-with-sqlalchemy/19175907?noredirect=1#comment28377422_19175907) comment/correction or I might have suggested something akin to:

```
Base.metadata.tables["ticket_daily_history"].create(bind = engine)
```

**Advise:**

The approach used in `build_daily_history_table` could be one of the least elegant ways of doing things, primarily for the reason that it is polluting/cluttering the [namespace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace).

Comment: I tried that but
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "autoPopulate.py", line 493, in <module>
    m_init()
  File "autoPopulate.py", line 422, in m_init
    state = success_state(ticket)
  File "autoPopulate.py", line 306, in success_state
    globals()[class_name].create(engine)
AttributeError: type object 'HMN_HistoricDay' has no attribute 'create'`

Comment: `HistoricDay.__table__.create(engine)`

Comment: With cymysql connector, I had to use `__table__.create(engine, checkfirst=True)`

Comment: From what I see, @javex 's comment is what most of us are looking for in here, so it may be useful to highlight it a bit more in the question.

Answer (score 23):

To create specific tables, giving `tables` parameter to `create_all()` method is enough.

```
Base.metadata.create_all(engine, tables=table_objects)
```

table_objects equals to:

```
table_objects = [HistoricDay.__table__]
```

or

```
table_objects = [Base.metadata.tables["historicday"]]
```

I showed one table here. You can increase the number of the tables as you wish.

Reference:
 http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData.create_all

Comment: The second option worked for me: Base.metadata.create_all(engine, tables=[Product.__table__]). Thanks

Answer (score 12):

Create all not exists tables with one line. It will check whether the table exists first by default.

```
Base.metadata.create_all(db_engine, Base.metadata.tables.values(),checkfirst=True)
```

Create one target table with `table_name`.

```
Base.metadata.create_all(db_engine, Base.metadata.tables[table_name],checkfirst=True)
```

It works perfectly with `declarative_base`.

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()
TABLE_PREFIX = "decision_"


class Stock(Base):
    __tablename__ = '{}stocks'.format(TABLE_PREFIX)

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

class StagePerformance(Base):
    __tablename__ = '{}stage_performance'.format(TABLE_PREFIX)

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    date = Column(DateTime)
    stock = relationship("Stock", back_populates="stage_performances")
    period = Column(Integer )
    open = Column(Float)
    high = Column(Float)
    low = Column(Float)
    close = Column(Float)
    change_ratio = Column(Float)
    turnover = Column(Float)
    volume = Column(Float)
```